# Which of these idioms is correct?

Tags: idioms

Which of the following two are the correct usage of the phrase?

"**Look on the bright side.**"

"
"**Look at the bright side.**"

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/look+on+the+bright+side

^ here it reads "On the bright side" is the correct idiom, but I just heard someone use "At the bright side" not over 3 minutes ago. ._.)

Comment: For all intensive purposes people sometimes write idioms slightly incorrectly. The correct one is "look on the bright side". To quote someone from a forum thread on this topic: *"I think "at" is probably wrong, and the accepted set phrase is definitely "look on the bright side". I think it is because one is not looking at a concrete "bright side" but it is somewhat akin to a general location or direction, as in "look on the left", or "look on the top"."*

Comment: @JohnClifford did you type that wrong intentionally? The correct phrase is "For all **intents and purposes**". It is a common error.

Comment: @Catija Yep, that was the joke. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual phrasing of the idiom you are interested in is

> Look **on** the bright side

which asks the listener to ***consider*** more positive meaning in a bad situation.

A popular example can be found [**here**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJUhlRoBL8M&t=0m25s)

> Look **at** the bright side

may have the same intent as

> *(If you)* look **at** the facts
>   *(If you)* look **at** the bright side

which tells the listener there are more positive meanings.

> Look **upon** the bright side

might also be used in a more poetic style and still have the same meaning.

Comment: https://www.loc.gov/resource/sm1877.00067.0/?sp=4 "Look upon" is archaic I think. A quick search only turns up instances from the 1800s.

Comment: Behold the bright side!